# How to measure the size of a barcode while using React Native Camera?

Tags: ios, react-native

Is it possible to know the pixel-wise size of a barcode object (width and height) while using React Native Camera library?
Or is there any other possible solution to know the size of a barcode from a taken image in an iOS app?

Comment: but... why exactly?

Comment: This is part of a project where the metric size of the barcode is known and then by knowing the pixel-wise size of the barcode, we can find the pixels per metric ratio of the image to be used for finding the metric size of other objects in the image.